# how to echo this kind of query

Tags: php, mysql

I search some query to Count the value of same row in my database I have `product_description` in my `table` called `delevery` where you can see list of all product and `quantity` where can see list the quantity of the product.

I found this code but I don't know how to echo this my my webpage?

```
SELECT quantity, count(*) as 'count quantity' 
FROM delivery 
GROUP BY product_description
```

Comment: you can check this in phpmyadmin

Comment: Who says phpMyAdmin is even installed or an option on this server?

Comment: So now you have two columns with the same name. That's great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will return JSON to your application

```
<?php

$DB_NAME = 'DATABASE_NAME';
$DB_HOST = 'DATABASE_HOST';
$DB_USER = 'DATABASE_USER';
$DB_PASS = 'DATABASE_PASSWORD';

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$yourValue = $request->yourValue;

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

$sql="SELECT quantity, count(*) as 'quantity' FROM delivery GROUP BY product_description";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

$result1 = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($result1, $row);
}

echo json_encode($result1);
```

?>

Comment: **Don't** use `mysql_*` functions. The extension is [deprecated and will be removed in the future](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
try to show your result with function var_dump();
$query="SELECT quantity, count(*) as 'quantity' FROM delivery GROUP BY product_description";


$result = mysql_query($query);



var_dump($result);
```